# Finalize CD/DVD after one write

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc, burning

I am looking to burn files to a CD or DVD and finalize it after the first write. I don't want to be able to add any other files in the future, regardless of the free space. I can't seem to find a program that does this, and "master" and "finalize" don't bring up the solution I want. The only thing I can think of is writing junk or filler data. (e.g. I write 100 MB of files. I fill the remainder with filler data so that the disc is full and cannot be written to again.)

Comment: Just use the built-in tool.  When ask which option you want to use, use the option, that closes the session permanently on the disk.

Comment: I was writing the comment in a rush.  I didn't care to put much effort into it.    Troubleshooting is a two-way street.  I was feeling discouraged because of the lack of clarity in your responses.  I am going to delete my other comments to clear the rubbish.  How you use the built-in tool is well documented.  If you choose to go into more detail update your question and I can provide some better responses.

Comment: I can delete mine as well. True, I did not originally provide what optical media I was using, nor the utility. However, I figured I provided enough relevant information. Anything additional, someone could ask and I'd provide.

Comment: MS seems to have patched out the 'finalize disc' option.  This question has become more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This software solved my issue: http://infrarecorder.org/

Choose Data Disc, and add files. Select Actions > Burn Compilation > to a Compact Disc. Accept all default values and hit OK. This uses the CDFS instead of UDF, which prevents any additional changes to the disc (specifically, using remaining space).